# nodejs bodyparser gives truncated value for string sent from axios using formdata

Tags: node.js, axios, multipartform-data, body-parser

We are using axios on the client(browser) side with formdata to send requests to the nodejs server. The nodejs server uses bodyparser along with express-fileupload for file uploads. The request sends meta data (json) to the server in string format. bodyparser on the server is set to 100mb for both json and urlencoded. Axios is setting the content-type to "multipart/form-data". This setup is working fine when the string size is less than 1mb. The problem arises when the string(meta) size increases more than 1mb, the server receives a truncated value of the meta. JSON parsing throws "**Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse**". Nginx is used for routing to the nodejs server. client_max_body_size on Nginx is set for 500M. Here is the client code sample

```
let fd = new FormData()
fd.append('uid',1);
fd.append('meta',"json string here");
axios({url:'http://localhost:9090/receivemeta',method:'POST',
    data: fd
}).then(resp=>{console.log(resp.data);}).catch(error=>{console.error(error.response.data)});
```

The server side is as follows

```
app.post('/receivemeta',async(req,res)=>{
   try{
      let meta = JSON.parse(req.body.meta);
      fs.writeJSONSync('/tmp/meta.json',meta,'utf-8');
      res.json({success:true})
   }catch(error){res.json({success:false,error:error});
})
```

Is bodyparser the issue here for failing with string data greater than 1mb?

Comment: "*bodyparser on the server is set to 100mb for both `json` and `urlencoded`*" - uh, `multipart/form-data` is neither of those two?

Comment: Yes, before the client was using application/json form but now recently it was switched to formdata, hence we never faced this size issue. for express-fileupload there was no options set. now have set the fieldSize and fieldSize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

body-parser is not used at all for `multipart/form-data` requests.

The middleware handling your request body data in this case is [express-fileupload](https://github.com/richardgirges/express-fileupload) which in turn uses [Busboy](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy).

The default limit for field size is 1MB.

Any size limits for fields should be configured along side file size limits

```js
app.use(fileUpload({
  limits: {
    fileSize: 100 * 1024 * 1024,
    fieldSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024, //  5MB
  },
}));
```

---

Unless you're uploading files, I would recommend you avoid `FormData` and stick to `application/json` requests

```js
axios.post("/receivemeta", {
  uid: 1,
  meta: {
    // whatever data here as a plain object, not JSON
  },
}, {
  baseURL: "http://localhost:9090/", // easier to set via env
});
```

and on the server-side, provided you've used the `express.json()` middleware...

```js
const { meta, uid } = req.body;
```

Comment: Thanks. Got it working. I was completely looking at the wrong side with focus fixed on bodyparser as with application/json header type(i.e without formdata) it was working. Spent nearly 24hours+ on this.. The client is using Axios from single point with formdata as they might upload file also.